# Render Django-CMS plugins differently on different splaceholders/templates

Tags: layout, django-templates, zurb-foundation, django-cms, overriding

Short version: I'd like to have the same kind of cmsplugin use different templates in different placeholders. Is this possible? Or, should I go and make my custom plugin?

Long version: Using Django and Django-CMS and using the `cmsplugin-video-youtube` plugin, I have two youtube videos on the home page and they are styled using Foundation 4's grid system to be stacked one and then another below it and at a certain 'breaking point' of the browser's width, they will be side-by-side. This is all working well.

Now I'd like to add some unlimited number of YouTube videos in a different `placeholder` that is in a different page, which is of a different template. And I would like to have them rendered one below the former and so on and on a certain 'breaking point' of the browser width they will be horizontal side-by-side pairs, one pair below the former and so on.

Since these YouTube video elements are of an unlimited, not predefined, number, I can't use the grid system. I figured I'd use the [block grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/block-grid.html) system. This has me create the elements as `<li>` elements inside a `<u>` element. This requires that I change the template for the `cmsplugin-video-youtube` element to render those `<li>` elements around the YouTubes. The problem with this is that if I override the template for this plugin, by supplying `templates/cmsplugin-video-youtube/embed.html`, it will also override it and alter it for the instances of this plugin that are in the home page. And I like them as they are.

So what I thought is that it would be beneficial to have a way of overriding the template for a plugin only for a specific `placeholder`. That would allow me to specify the YouTube's rendering in a specific `placeholder` in my other page and not affect the instances of this plugin in my home page, which I like as they are.

Is there such an option - to override the template of a plugin for a specific `placeholder`?

Otherwise, I thought that this might require a custom plugin that is based on the existing `cmsplugin-video-youtube`, perhaps a subclass of it, I would assume, that would then have the template that I require, with the `<li>` elements, for this other page.

A different approach would be to attempt to iterate over the instances of the plugin instance and render them with the whole `<ul><li>` thing around them, one by one. [I've inquired about this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324664/how-to-iterate-over-cms-plugin-instances-from-a-page-in-a-django-template) and according to some answers I got, it would seem to be not the most easiest route.

What would be your approach to this, please?

I've not received an answer yet. Please, even a pointer would be something!

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is very old. .but hopefully anyone with same problem will find this useful.

Looking at sourcecode for CMSPluginBase:

https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/plugin_base.py

```
context['placeholder'] = placeholder
```

Placeholder is passed as context in the render method.

So in the template you can use that to to render different output.  A good example for this:

https://github.com/stefanfoulis/cmsplugin-filer/blob/develop/cmsplugin_filer_image/templates/cmsplugin_filer_image/plugins/image/default.html