# django cms [aldryn newsblog] replace template for plugin

Tags: django, templates, django-cms

I need to replace same plugin template on different subpages - e.g. on frontpage I need specific slider template for latest articles, in detail article I need small list, on search result without images etc.
[note: everything about aldryn newsblog app - I don't mean my own plugin!]

*(something like custom template per plugin instance)

How to replace it ? Extending template is not quite what I need - inheritance is from bottom - from lower subtemplate to base.html - but that plugin have hardcoded lower template.

Tons of IF block in template is irrational then we think in MVC.
*( like here [Render Django-CMS plugins differently on different splaceholders/templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759313/render-django-cms-plugins-differently-on-different-splaceholders-templates) )

Or maybe just write custom template with using hardcoded including plugins ? But using django cms placeholder editor is very useful and it'll be better to keep working in that way :///

So, I create front.html base template for frontpage,
put some plugins to placeholders - and need to replace subtemplates for this plugins only in this front.html and keep subtemplates for that plugin in other places - this is main goal.

It will be the best, when django cms / aldryn newsblog provide option "custom template" per plugin instance :|
( like this one http://www.ilian.io/django-cms-plugins-with-selectable-template/ )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (it's late here), you need a way to override plugin templates on a plugin instance basis because hacking django templates is not the way to go (I agree).

Django CMS does allow you to override plugin templates on an instance basis.
As shown in http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/custom_plugins.html?highlight=get_render_template#the-simplest-plugin

In your CMSPluginBase subclass add the following:

```
  def get_render_template(self, context, instance, placeholder):
      # criteria goes here
      return 'sometemplate.html'
```

As far as how to know which template to render when (criteria), you can do a few things.

**Use the page's reverse id:**

```
page = instance.page

templates = {
    'homepage': 'plugin_home.html',
    'about': 'plugin_about.html',
    'contact': 'plugin_contact.html',
}
return templates[plugin.page.reverse_id]
```

This approach has a few drawbacks:

- Relies on plugin being bound to a page. (plugins can live outside of pages)
- Can only work with pages that    have reverse id set and reverse ids
  are unique per page which means    you would have to list reverse id
  for every page you want to change    template for.

**Use a *page* extension to set a category per page:**

Checkout http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/extending_page_title.html
With this approach you can then set some sort of category to multiple pages and so you can target multiple pages in one shot like so:

```
    page = instance.page
    extension = get_page_extension(page) # Check out docs for this
    templates = {
        'category_1': 'plugin_category_1.html',
        'category_2': 'plugin_category_2.html',
        'category_3': 'plugin_category_3.html',
    }
    return templates[extension.category.name]
```

Pros:

- Can target multiple pages in one shot

Cons:

- Relies on plugin being bound to a page.
- A bit more complex

**Use a template context variable:**
In your templates, depending on how you're rendering your plugins, you can
provide a context variable like so:

```
{% with category='category_1' %}
{% placeholder 'content' %}
{% endwith %}
```

or

```
{% with category='category_1' %}
{% render_plugin yourplugin %}
{% endwith %}
```

Then in your `get_render_template` method you can access this context variable and do the following:

```
# Use .get() to provide fallback
category = context['category']

templates = {
   'category_1': 'plugin_category_1.html',
   'category_2': 'plugin_category_2.html',
   'category_3': 'plugin_category_3.html',
}
return templates[category]
```

Pros:

- No extra models.
- Can target multiple pages in one shot.

Cons:

- The only one I can think of is these random `{% with %}` in
  templates.

I completely missed the newblog part, so in order to override the newsblog plugins or any plugin, just subclass the plugin class you want to override and unregister the original and then register yours, make sure yours has the same class name.

Maybe you can make the whole template logic above into a mixin to use throughout your project.

Comment: One thing - not "my plugin" but Aldryn NewsBlog app provide own plugins - and I need to adjust output. So best solution will be to replace render_template on the fly - in template or something similar - but I can't hack Aldryn NewsBlog app code. So only way is something via templates or custom app extending NewsBlog.

Comment: If it's something you plan to do on multiple apps, I suggest you replace the plugin as described in the answer. This way you only override the template rendered and not anything else, so upgrading would be much easier.

Comment: Hmm can you recommend any blog/article addon for django cms ? I need to write some apps for my website, so basic apps like blog and for articles I want to use something released - newsblog look nice, but I have many problmes with it - many bugs and weird logic sometimes.

Comment: Would be good if you can file newsblog bugs on github, aside from that there's also djangocms-blog

Comment: Yeah I know, part I post to the issue queue already. DjangoCMS Blog is too small app - and provide only blog feature - NewsBlog is nice with multi app configs give me opportunity to separate (partially only..) blog and articles section.
Anyway, I think I'll write my own app for that :/

Answer (score -2):

I've always wanted to give Zinnia a look, but I'm too far into working with NewsBlog on a site right now to do it (and blogs have already been posted and whatnot). You can always just add a few extra placeholders in the template (it's not the most efficient *looking* thing ever, but it's no load on the framework if you add a placeholder and leave it blank), that way they aren't static, and then you can put whatever plugins you want to inside of them. You can customize each component in NewsBlog pretty easily by just adding whatever you want in the structure mode. Things get trickier when it comes to having multiple blogs that act differently, but even then, as long as you're not adding components into the static placeholders provided by NewsBlog (or as I so elegantly learned it, "don't put the stuff in the blocky-things with the pins next to them), you can create different namespace for the different blogs (either in the admin, under "Configs" in the NewsBlog section, or when creating a new page and hooking it to the NewsBlog app), and you can have different templates on different blogs.

EDIT: This is a really excellent resource for touching up NewBlog without throwing the baby out with the bathwater (after three months of learning DjangoCMS, I'm still finding myself referencing it for fine-tuning pieces of NewsBlog, and to refresh my grasp on templatetags and other things that are overwhelming and have quickly left my brain along the way): https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2016/02/16/build-a-website-without-knowing-python-django-part-two/

*I linked to part two, as the first part deals with how to initially setup a project, and I assumed it probably wasn't relevant. Then again, if you're using Aldryn, there are some useful bits in there that can extrapolate if you're having trouble with customizing the boilerplate (or other things you'd like to configure that an Aldryn setup handles for you -- which is super awesome most of the times, but when it's not super awesome, it's usually super frustrating :)

Comment: Not sure why that was downvoted (I'm still learning, so I'd honestly like to know if I'm way off base on that approach!), but the NewsBlog article search plugin, code [here](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog/blob/master/aldryn_newsblog/boilerplates/bootstrap3/static/js/addons/cl.newsblog.js) , was made using Angelo Dini's class.js javascript framework; it might be worth looking into the framework's [plugin creation abilities](https://classjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/contributing/plugins.html#creating-a-plugin) , they seem to be a very seamless way to extend NewsBlog.