# Django CMS plugin switch between different templates

Tags: python, django, templates, plugins, content-management-system

For example i have very simple news plugin

Part of models.py:

```
class SimpleNews(CMSPlugin):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    excerpt = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

And two different templates, one for short news and one for full news:

Short:

```
<h1>{{ instance.title }}</h1>
<p>
  {{ instance.excerpt|safe }}
</p>
```

Full:

```
<img src={{instance.image}}/>
<h1>{{ instance.title }}</h1>
<p>
  {{ instance.text|safe }}
</p>
```

I need to switch between this templates depending on adress. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i find answer by myself.
Vewy useful link here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34804271/6198007.
If switching is slow you'll need to add

```
cache=False
```

in your plugin in cms_plugins.py, after that all should be fine.

Sorry for my english.